# Is there WM9Codecs. for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, codec, windows-media-player

I tried to download the following: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=507
but I get an error message:

[image: error message]

Is there version of this for Server 2008?
I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that [Media Player Codec Pack](http://download.cnet.com/Media-Player-Codec-Pack/3000-13632_4-10749065.html) includes all WM9Codecs and working on Windows Server 2008.
This pack does the job!